# How to deploy docker micro services individually using Gitlab CI and allow them to talk?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, nameko

I'm working on trying to create a micro service system able to be deployed using docker, and I've run into a few conceptual road blocks that I'd love some help with. So each of my micro services are running on Python's Nameko framework with RabbitMQ as the message broker, and each of the services are in their own git repo. I'm trying to figure out how I can create a gitlab CI deployment system for each service such that when master is changed, for any perticular service, the container gets rebuilt and auto deployed to my docker swarm **My current attempt at a gitlab CI config**:

```
stage: 
  - build
  - deploy

build:  
  image: docker
  variables: 
    REG_HOST: 'local-registry-url'

  script:
    - docker login to local image repo
    - docker build -t $REG_HOST/$SOME_TAG
    - docker push $REG_HOST/$SOME_TAG

deploy: 
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker login to local image repo
    - docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=docker-stack-compose.yml

  only:
    - master
```

I am creating a new `docker-stack-compose.yml` per service, but I'm not sure how to define a dependency that all of my services rely on, such as rabbitMQ without redefining it in each of my `docker-stack-compose.yml` and would that even work? Also how would I put them all on the same network?

**This is what my current work in progress compose file looks like for a test service:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    container_name: io-test
    image: local-registry-url/service-name
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - service-net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2

networks:
  default:
    external: service-net
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Opinion: if the message broker is a central infrastructure component, with persistent state that can't be trivially moved, don't run it in Swarm; do create a DNS name for it; and make the broker's location configurable via an environment variable.

Comment: When u said “message broker” above in your question, did u mean “message producer”?

Comment: @Light.G no.. according to RabbitMQ's home page they say, "RabbitMQ is a message broker", so I'm just sticking with their terminology. I'm not familiar with a the term, "message producer." In this context I think Namiko would maybe be the "message producer" and it sends a message to the message broker i.e. RabbitMQ which then hands that message off to another Nameko service to be handheld.

Comment: So you need to link a RabbitMQ container to your actual container ? I think you might be interested by [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image-and-services)